# Ruby string interpolation

Tags: ruby, xpath, string-interpolation

How do I insert

```
#{stock_sym}
```

into

```
stock_price = dom.xpath('//*[@id="yfs_l84_aapl"]').first.content
```

replacing `aapl`?

Answer (score 4):

String interpolation only works with double quotes:

```
"//*[@id='yfs_l84_#{stock_sym}']"
```

Comment: Check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings

Answer (score -1):

```
stock_price = dom.xpath("//*[@id='yfs_l84_#{stock_sym}']").first.content
```